# How to select all the items above threshold or at least the first item?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have been stuck on this problem for a day and it seems there is no out of the box easy way to do this so here I am.

To replicate the database we can use these queries

```
CREATE (:Score {value: 0.2})
CREATE (:Score {value: 0.3})
CREATE (:Score {value: 0.4})
CREATE (:Score {value: 0.5})
CREATE (:Score {value: 0.38})
CREATE (:Score {value: 0.35})
```

What I want is basically to return all the nodes whose value is above a certain threshold and if no such nodes are available then just return the one that has the max value

For example if the threshold is `0.35` then I want the query to return the nodes

```
(Score {value: 0.4})
(Score {value: 0.5})
(Score {value: 0.38})
```

because all of the above nodes have values greater than thea threshold

But if the threshold is `0.6` then it should just return the node

```
(Score {value: 0.5})
```

because no nodes qualify this threshold but 0.5 is the max value

Answer (score 0):

Using just plain Cypher, you could do this, but it may not be efficient depending on the number of Score nodes you have:

```
MATCH (n:Score) 
WHERE n.value>0.35
WITH collect(n) AS nodes
MATCH (n:Score)
WITH max(n.value) as value, nodes
MATCH (n:Score) WHERE n.value=value
RETURN CASE WHEN size(nodes)=0 THEN n ELSE nodes END
```

APOC's `when` should perform better but you should try it out on your graph:

```
MATCH (n:Score) 
WHERE n.value>0.35
WITH collect(n) as nodes

CALL apoc.when(
  size(nodes)=0,
  'MATCH (n:Score) WITH max(n.value) AS value, nodes MATCH (n:Score) WHERE n.value=value RETURN n',
  'UNWIND nodes AS node RETURN node',
  {nodes:nodes})
YIELD value
RETURN value
```

Comment: The problem with this is the `score` node is derived after a lot of computations. I cannot just run the match for it again inside apoc if there are no matches based on threshold. Is there any I can copy it temporary so I do not have to match it again inside apoc ?

Comment: What do you mean by a lot of computations? Is it a property on a node or something else?

Comment: I mean that `(n:Score)` thing is not readily available in the DB. There are a lot of computations before to compute that score. Its like a 50 line query before that. I just put it like that to simplify things for everyone. Ideally its a bunch of math formulas and lot of where clauses and other things to calculate this Score node. So I cant just `MATCH (n:Score)` if there are no matches above threshold. I need to be able to save the results of those computations and somehow make a temp variable that first checks if there is any above threshold and if not selects the first one.

Comment: Oh ok...would have been good to say that in the question :-) 
The way you model this could significantly change the query so it would be good to share more details